# html - presentacion basica de datos

Tags: html, bash

es la primera vez que trato con html y no sé qué fallos estoy cometiendo.

El dataset que tengo es este (train.csv):

```
PassengerId,Survived,Pclass,Name,Sex,Age,SibSp,Parch,Ticket,Fare,Cabin,Embarked
1,0,3,"Braund, Mr. Owen Harris",male,22,1,0,A/5 21171,7.25,,S
2,1,1,"Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)",female,38,1,0,PC 17599,71.2833,C85,C
3,1,3,"Heikkinen, Miss. Laina",female,26,0,0,STON/O2. 3101282,7.925,,S
4,1,1,"Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)",female,35,1,0,113803,53.1,C123,S
5,0,3,"Allen, Mr. William Henry",male,35,0,0,373450,8.05,,S
6,0,3,"Moran, Mr. James",male,,0,0,330877,8.4583,,Q
7,0,1,"McCarthy, Mr. Timothy J",male,54,0,0,17463,51.8625,E46,S
8,0,3,"Palsson, Master. Gosta Leonard",male,2,3,1,349909,21.075,,S
9,1,3,"Johnson, Mrs. Oscar W (Elisabeth Vilhelmina Berg)",female,27,0,2,347742,11.1333,,S
10,1,2,"Nasser, Mrs. Nicholas (Adele Achem)",female,14,1,0,237736,30.0708,,C
```

El script que he preparado en un archivo bash es:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Este script generará un HTML
# Mostramos los marcadores HTML iniciales.
echo "<html>"
echo "<body>"
echo "<table border='1'>"
# Lectura del fichero obtenido anteriormente.
# Cada fila contiene un equipamiento. Los campos están separados por ;

input="train.csv"
i=1
while IFS= read -r line
do
nom='echo $line | cut -d ";" -f1'
via='echo $line | cut -d ";" -f2'
echo "<tr><td>$nom</td><td>$via</td></tr>"
done < "$input"

# Mostramos los marcadores HTML finales.
echo "</table>"
echo "</body>"
echo "</html>"
```

El resultado que obtengo es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cómo puedo hacer para que se representen los valores y no lo que actualmente me aparece?

Gracias.

Comment: Cambia la comilla simple del inicio y del final del echo por un acento grave (o invertido, no se como ponerlo aqui, me lo interpreta mal), asi ejecutará ese comando

Comment: @masterguru, te refieres a  esta? ' ` '

Comment: @masterguru, entender sí, pero lo he cambiado en todas las que sale ```echo``` (7 veces en total) y me sale error sintáctico en todas las líneas

Comment: ejem, perdona, me referia solo a las asignaciones `nom=` y `via=`

Comment: @masterguru, ok, así entonces ' `echo $line | cut -d ";" -f1` '

Comment: aun asi, no parece que haga mucho caso, pues tan solo te hace el `echo`, pero no el `cut`... a mi me devuelve cosas asi: `<td>10,1,2,"Nasser, Mrs. Nicholas (Adele Achem)",female,14,1,0,237736,30.0708,,C</td><td>10,1,2,"Nasser, Mrs. Nicholas (Adele Achem)",female,14,1,0,237736,30.0708,,C</td>`

Comment: a mí ni eso. sólo ```<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>```

Comment: eso es que no me has entendido o algo no funciona bien... prueba asi pues:  `nom=$(echo $line | cut -d ";" -f1)`

Comment: @masterguru, ahora me salen 2 columnas con todos los valores. Algo es algo.

Comment: @masterguru, veo que cambiando en el ```cut``` el ';' por ',' me vuelve a fallar todo pero en cambio mi dataset sí que está separado por ','. Sabes qué puede estar ocurriendo?

Comment: Lo del nombre con `awk` seria asi:  `nom=$(echo $line | awk -F \" '/".*"/{print $2}')`

Comment: @masterguru, usaba ```via``` y ```nom``` por ser código aprovechado y con ellos hacer las pruebas. Ya he podido obtener toda la tabla finalmente. Ahora me quedan hacer unas cuantas mejoras sobre ella.

Comment: @masterguru, perdona y gracias. Soy muy nuevo en este foro y creo que es la primera vez que consigo resolverme una duda (tras muchas respuestas vuestras) Hoy los planetas se alinean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que he mejorado el código de tu propia respuesta, la cual tras ejecutarla me daba esto, donde los nombres aparecian en varias columnas y se perdian datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que he utilizado:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Este script generará un HTML
# Mostramos los marcadores HTML iniciales.

# Creamos una variable donde almacenar la salida
OUTPUT="<html>
<head>
<link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel="stylesheet" integrity='sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3' crossorigin='anonymous'>
</head>
<body>
<div class='container'>
<div class='table-responsive'>
<table class='table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-sm caption-top'>
<caption>Lista de pasajeros</caption>
"

# Lectura del fichero obtenido anteriormente.
# Cada fila contiene un equipamiento. Los campos están separados por ,
input="train.csv"

# Inicializamos un contador para detectar el encabezado
let count=0

# Recorremos el archivo de entrada linea a linea
while IFS= read -r line
do
  # a la primera linea le pondremos un encabezado
  if [ $count -eq 0 ]
    then
      # agregamos la cabecera a la salida
      OUTPUT+="
      <thead class='table-dark'>
      <tr>
        <th>PassengerId</th>
        <th>Survived</th>
        <th>Pclass</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Sex</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>SibSp</th>
        <th>Parch</th>
        <th>Ticket</th>
        <th>Fare</th>
        <th>Cabin</th>
        <th>Embarked</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      ";
      #  sumamos 1 al contador de lineas
      let count=$count+1
    else
      # sumamos 1 al contador de lineas
      let count=$count+1

      # primero buscamos el nombre y lo asignamos a la variable nom
      # comprobamos que solo haya dos comillas por si acaso
      comprobacioncomillas=$(echo $line | sed 's/[^"]//g' | awk '{ print length }')
      if [ $comprobacioncomillas -eq 2 ]
        then
          # asignamos el campo name
          Name=$(echo $line | awk -F \" '/".*"/{print $2}')
          # despues borramos ese campo de la linea para poder usar el cut en el resto
          line=$(echo $line | sed 's/,".*"//g')

      # asignamos los otros campos sabiendo que hay un campo menos
          PassengerId=$(echo $line | cut -d "," -f1)
          Survived=$(echo $line | cut -d "," -f2)
          Pclass=$(echo $line | cut -d "," -f3)
          # Name=$(echo $line | cut -d "," -f4)
          Sex=$(echo $line | cut -d "," -f4)
          Age=$(echo $line | cut -d "," -f5)
          SibSp=$(echo $line | cut -d "," -f6)
          Parch=$(echo $line | cut -d "," -f7)
          Ticket=$(echo $line | cut -d "," -f8)
          Fare=$(echo $line | cut -d "," -f9)
          Cabin=$(echo $line | cut -d "," -f10)
          Embarked=$(echo $line | cut -d "," -f11)

      # agregamos el registro a la tabla
          OUTPUT+="
          <tr>
            <td>$PassengerId</td>
            <td>$Survived</td>
            <td>$Pclass</td>
            <td>$Name</td>
            <td>$Sex</td>
            <td>$Age</td>
            <td>$SibSp</td>
            <td>$Parch</td>
            <td>$Ticket</td>
            <td>$Fare</td>
            <td>$Cabin</td>
            <td>$Embarked</td>
          </tr>"
       else
         ## si no hay dos comillas solo
         echo "Error: Las comillas son distintas de 2:"
         echo $line
       break
     fi
  fi
done < "$input"

# Ponemos los marcadores HTML finales en la variable de salida output
OUTPUT+="
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>"

# mostramos la salida
echo $OUTPUT
```

El código tiene sus propios comentarios y diria que es facil de seguir.

La parte más importante ha sido para solucionar el problema del campo entrecomillado que contenia comas, donde al final he decidido encontrarlo primero y asignarlo a la variable `Name` para luego destruirlo de la linea con un `sed`, quedando los otros valores sin problemas listos para ser usados con `cut`.

Lo de ponerle el bootstrap es porque lo tengo mucho por la mano, pero se puede eliminar facilmente quitando su referencia en el `<head>` y borrando todas las clases que he puesto.

Al final ha quedado asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

El problema estaba en las líneas mal creadas
`PassengerId=$(echo $line | cut -d "," -f1)`

El nuevo código resulta así:

```
#echo "<html>"
#echo "<body>"
#echo "<table border='1'>"
#echo "<tbody tr:nth-child(2n+1){background: #D5DBF4;}"

echo "<html>"
echo "<head>"
echo "<style>"
echo "tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {"
echo "   background: #D5DBF4;"
echo "}"
echo "</style>"
echo "<head>"
echo "<body>"
echo "<table border='1'>"



# Lectura del fichero obtenido anteriormente.
# Cada fila contiene un pasajero. Los campos están separados por ,

input="train.csv"
i=1
while IFS= read -r line
do

PassengerId=$(echo $line | cut -d "," -f1)
Survived=$(echo $line | cut -d "," -f2)
Pclass=$(echo $line | cut -d "," -f3)
Name=$(echo $line | cut -d "," -f4)
Sex=$(echo $line | cut -d "," -f5)
Age=$(echo $line | cut -d "," -f6)
SibSp=$(echo $line | cut -d "," -f7)
Parch=$(echo $line | cut -d "," -f8)
Ticket=$(echo $line | cut -d "," -f9)
Fare=$(echo $line | cut -d "," -f10)
Cabin=$(echo $line | cut -d "," -f11)

Embarked=$(echo $line | cut -d "," -f12)
#echo "<tr><td>$PassengerId</td><td>$Survived</td><td>$Pclass</td><td>$Name</td><td>$Sex</td><td>$Age</td><td>$SibSp</td><td>$Parch</td><td>$Ticket</td><td>$Fare</td><td>$Cabin</td><td>$Embarked</td></t>

echo "<tr><th>$PassengerId</th><th>$Survived</th><th>$Pclass</th><th>$Name</th><th>$Sex</th><th>$Age</th><th>$SibSp</th><th>$Parch</th><th>$Ticket</th><th>$Fare</th><th>$Cabin</th><th>$Embarked</th></tr>
done < "$input"

# Mostramos los marcadores HTML finales.
echo "</table>"
echo "</body>"
echo "</html>"
```

Este nuevo código presenta algún cambio de formato adicionalmente (fuera del alcance de la cuestión que planteaba aquí inicialmente)

Comment: Diria que las comas de los nombres te la han jugado: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HodaX.png (ya me parecia a mi raro que con el cut lo hubieras conseguido)